# How to calculate the difference between two dates with a return value type of integer in Informix?

Tags: date, informix

I am using an Informix database. I want to get the difference between two dates, and the data type of return value must be an integer. The SQL looks like:

```
select (today - to_date('20121201','%Y%m%d'))  from your_table_name
```

However, when I execute the SQL it returns 45 and certainly the computed value is not the integer type.
What's the date type of the value? How can I cast the value to integer?

Comment: It is returning INTERVAL, you need to cast it to integer.

Comment: Thanks.I get a way to resolve the question.Just like that: select ((today - to_date('20121201','%Y%m%d'))::INTERVAL day(9) TO day::char(10)::int) td  from tb_dis_controll

Comment: jason: add your comment as answer, so others will see that this problem is resolved. In a few days you will be able to accept it. You will also benefit being upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TO_DATE function is an Oracle import, and returns an Oracle DATE type in Oracle (hence the name), but the Oracle DATE type corresponds to an Informix DATETIME type.  So, the Informix implementation of the TO_DATE() function returns a DATETIME type.

#### Problem

```
SELECT TODAY AS TODAY,
       TO_DATE('20121201', '%Y%m%d') AS raw_to_date,
       (TODAY - TO_DATE('20121201','%Y%m%d')) AS raw_difference
  FROM sysmaster:informix.sysdual;

today       raw_to_date                   raw_difference
DATE        DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION(5)  INTERVAL DAY(8) TO DAY
2013-01-16  2012-12-01 00:00:00.00000     46
```

#### Solution

The solution for your expression is to apply the DATE function to the output of TO_DATE, or cast it to type DATE.

```
SELECT DATE(TO_DATE('20121201', '%Y%m%d'))          AS date_to_date,
       CAST(TO_DATE('20121201', '%Y%m%d') AS DATE)  AS cast_to_date,
            TO_DATE('20121201', '%Y%m%d')::DATE     AS colon_to_date,
       (TODAY - DATE(TO_DATE('20121201','%Y%m%d'))) AS date_difference
  FROM sysmaster:informix.sysdual;

date_to_date  cast_to_date  colon_to_date  date_difference
DATE          DATE          DATE           INTEGER
2012-12-01    2012-12-01    2012-12-01     46
```

Comment: Jonathan,I appreciate your help very much.TODAY -DATE(TO_DATE('20121201','%Y%m%d')),the result is integer.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between two dates should be an integer. You should only get an `INTERVAL` when computing the difference between `DATETIME` values.

I don't have an Informix instance handy right now, but I suspect the use of the `to_date()` function is resulting in `DATETIME` math.

I can see you've come up with a solution, but try the following, which would be a *lot* simpler:

```
SELECT today - TO_DATE('20121201', '%Y%m%d')::DATE AS td FROM tb_dis_controll
```

Comment: Yes,ret,you got it.I find another way like that: select today-DATE('20121201') into ret from tb_dis_controll,and it returns an integer.Thanks very much.