# How to get the difference between two dates (informix)?

Tags: sql, date, stored-procedures, informix

How to get the difference between two dates (informix) in integer format  like that

---

```
day = 15
mon = 2
year = 1
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331328/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-with-a-return-value-type-of-in

Comment: @Rezoan : thanks but it gets the difference in one integer value . i want it in format `(day,mon,year)`

Comment: You've not expressed in the question how the two date values are stored.  You've shown one fragmentary date value.  Are the dates in your application, or in the database?  How are they stored in either case?  Give an example of two date values and the result you expect.  Be ready to explain what you want from differences such as '2014-02-14' - '2014-01-31', '2013-01-01' - '2012-02-29', etc.  When you say "I want the difference in the format `(day, mon, year)`", you need to define exactly how you think the computation will proceed.  You'll be creating a user-defined type, no doubt, for the job.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler :thanks a lot for your explanation , i want some thing like that `(m,d,y) - (m,d,y) = (m,d,y)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two sets of date/time values in Informix: DATE and DATETIME.

The DATE type is oldest (it was in the precursor to the SQL-based Informix), and represents the integer number of days since a reference date (where day 0 is 1899-12-31, so day 1 was 1900-01-01).

You get the difference between two DATE values in days by subtracting one from the other.

The DATETIME system is newer (but still old — circa 1990).  You can take the difference between two DATETIME YEAR TO DAY values and get a result that is an INTERVAL DAY TO DAY (essentially the number of days).

You could also take the difference between two DATETIME YEAR TO MONTH values and get a result that is an INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH.

However, there is no way to get a difference in years, months and days because there is no simple way to deduce that value.  In fact, ISO SQL recognizes two classes of INTERVAL: those in the YEAR-MONTH group, and those in the DAY-SECOND group.  You can't have an INTERVAL that crosses the MONTH/DAY barrier.

Answer (score 2):

Use the MDY function :

```
select mdy(2,15,2014) - mdy(1,15,2014) from sysmaster:sysdual
```